# Creating a GUI on Borland c++

Tags: c++, user-interface, borland-c++

My name is Guillermo and I'm studing Computer Sciences at college. For my final project, I have to build a game on Borland C++ and I was curious about making a GUI for it

The game is really simple. Create a matriz dimension 4x4 (with 16 elements) and fill it with random numbers from 1 to 15 and one empty space. The user/player would have to sort the numbers (1, 2, 3....15)

My "idea" of a GUI came from my old days having fun with MS VB6. Currently, I'm running Borland under wine on Ubuntu but I have no idea about making a GUI since I started with C++ a couple of months ago.

Answer (score 1):

Borland has its own GUI library with IDE support (<s>VCL?</s> comment says OWL).  Your GUI can easily be done with the built-in elements.  You'll have to check to see if the resulting GUI can run under WINE (probably).

Comment: Borland C++ did not have the VCL. It used OWL. C++Builder is required to use the VCL in C++

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look into [wxWidgets](http://www.wxwidgets.org/) and [Qt](http://qt.nokia.com/products/) that are both really good GUI engines meant primarily for creating forms. If you want to go further and draw your forms line by line (or simply create whatever tickles your fancy) then I reccomend [OpenGL](http://www.opengl.org/). You will have to spend some time learning them but once you do then they will be invaluable in the future projects that you do.